# How to block a small IP range in csf

Tags: ip, csf, block

I'm looking for a way to block a small ip range in csf, e.g. `151.80.31.103 to 151.80.31.115`

I know how to block each ip by issuing a cmmand `csf -d IP`, but it is a lot more effective to have a way to block a small set of ip range, as the given example.

I have searched for a while, but not finding any relevant information.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SSH access, you can manually edit the file /etc/csf/csf.deny with vim or emacs or your favorite text editor.

Here's a portion of the top of that file with some comments:

```
# The following IP addresses will be blocked in iptables
# One IP address per line
# CIDR addressing allowed with a quaded IP (e.g. 192.168.254.0/24)
# Only list IP addresses, not domain names (they will be ignored)
#
# Note: If you add the text "do not delete" to the comments of an entry then
# DENY_IP_LIMIT will ignore those entries and not remove them
```

Given that information, use a subnet calculator (such as [this one from MXtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/SubnetCalculator.aspx)) to determine the smaller subnet. Given your criteria, one possible subnet suggested by mxtoolbox would be 151.80.31.96/27, which would filter everything from 151.80.31.96 through 151.80.31.127.

Make sure that you restart CSF afterwards with `csf -r` and then restart lfd with `lfd -r`.

Comment: Thanks @David W for your answer, however, i'm asking for the way to block a small ip range as in the given example, not individual IP and not the entire subnet. Not sure whether that is possible, since i can't find any relevant info on the internet

Comment: You can block a smaller subnet. I'll edit the answer for clarity.